# How to adjust Wordpress Twitter Tools PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to update this function so that it also imports a link to the status and the time it was posted.

Here's the original

```
function do_tweet_post($tweet) {
    global $wpdb;
    remove_action('publish_post', 'aktt_notify_twitter', 99);
    $data = array(
        'post_content' => $wpdb->escape(aktt_make_clickable($tweet-> tw_text))
        , 'post_title' => $wpdb->escape(trim_add_elipsis($tweet->tw_text, 30))
        , 'post_date' => get_date_from_gmt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tweet->tw_created_at))
        , 'post_category' => array($this->blog_post_category)
        , 'post_status' => 'publish'
        , 'post_author' => $wpdb->escape($this->blog_post_author)
    );
}
```

The element that I'm trying to edit is `'post_content'`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
...
'post_content' => $wpdb->escape(aktt_make_clickable(
    $tweet-> tw_text.' from '.
    '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/1beb/statuses/"'.
    tw_id.'>Twitter</a> '.
    tw_created_at
))
...
```

I'm not very familiar with PHP so I don't know if my syntax is correct, or how to deal with this particular type of referencing (`->`). I recall that you can concatenate strings using `''.''.''.` etc, but not sure if it's valid for a case like this.

I apologize for the lack of context, if there's something else I can add to make it clearer, please advise.

TIA

**UPDATE**

---

Here is aktt_make_clickable for passerby:

```
function aktt_make_clickable($tweet) {
    $tweet .= ' ';
    $tweet = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(^|\s)@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\W)/'
            , create_function(
                '$matches'
                , 'return aktt_profile_link($matches[2], \' @\', $matches[3]);'
            )
            , $tweet
    );
    $tweet = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|\s)#([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\W)/'
        , create_function(
            '$matches'
            , 'return aktt_hashtag_link($matches[2], \' #\', \'\');'
        )
        , $tweet
    );

    if (function_exists('make_chunky')) {
        return make_chunky($tweet);
    }
    else {
        return make_clickable($tweet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed out the `$tweet` object on your code.

Try this:

```
'post_content' => $wpdb->escape(aktt_make_clickable($tweet-> tw_text.' from '.
        '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/1beb/statuses/"'.
        $tweet->tw_id.'>Twitter</a> '.$tweet->tw_created_at
))
```

#### Updated after seeing the `aktt_make_clickable()` code update from original poster:

Since you are hacking the plugin to make it display your own text, I guess you should be able to enter the link directly:

```
'post_content' => '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/1beb/statuses/"'.
        $tweet->tw_id.'>'.$tweet->tw_text.'</a> '.$tweet->tw_created_at,
```

(I noticed that you wish to insert author as well but from your code I cannot tell what's the proper variable name for author).

Comment: Thanks for the help with syntax. Making these changes buggers the plugin (no valid header). I think it has something to do with the wrapping and also aktt_make_clickable. I'll update the post with that function as well so people can see what it does.

Comment: Still breaks, and I think the code is off a bit. Tried this (an adjustment). `$tweet->tw_text.'<a href="http://www.twitter.com/1beb/statuses/'.$tweet->tw_id.'">Twitter</a>'.$tweet->tw_created_at` the comma follows on the next line in my code view. The goal is to show "STATUS from Twitter(linktoSTATUSonTWITTER) DATE"

Comment: Try `'post_content' => '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/1beb/statuses/"'.$tweet->tw_id.'>'.$tweet->tw_text.'</a> '.$tweet->tw_created_at`

Comment: Same issue, the plugin does not have a valid header. Thanks for trying tho.